# jQueryUi input[inputIndex].hasOwnProperty is not a function

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, jquery, locker-service

I'm trying to use jQueryUi V1.11.4 is a Salesforce Summer 17' Sandbox and I get this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: input[inputIndex].hasOwnProperty is not a function
throws at /resource/1498467744000/packageJson/package/jqueryUi.js:471:29 TypeError: input[inputIndex].hasOwnProperty is not a function
    at Function.$.widget.extend (/resource/1498467744000/packageJson/package/jqueryUi.js:471)
    at Function.$.widget.extend (/resource/1498467744000/packageJson/package/jqueryUi.js:477)
    at Function.$.widget.extend (/resource/1498467744000/packageJson/package/jqueryUi.js:477)
    at Function.$.widget.extend (/resource/1498467744000/packageJson/package/jqueryUi.js:475)
    at Function.$.widget (/resource/1498467744000/packageJson/package/jqueryUi.js:426)
    at /resource/1498467744000/packageJson/package/jqueryUi.js:8107
    at $.ui (/resource/1498467744000/packageJson/package/jqueryUi.js:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/resource/1498467744000/packageJson/package/jqueryUi.js:18)
    at $globalEvalIIFE$ (/resource/1498467744000/packageJson/package/jqueryUi.js:16620)
    at safeEval (safeEval.html?id=Custom:115)
```

Now according to [this blog post from Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html) I should be able to use it safely with LockerService activated.

Does somebody has any insight on what could cause this issue ?

**EDIT** : Here is the code used to call the libraries :

```
  <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
          $Resource.packageJson + '/package/jquery.js',
          $Resource.packageJson + '/package/jqueryUi.js',
          $Resource.packageJson + '/package/bootstrap.js',
          $Resource.packageJson + '/package/jquery.fancybox.js')}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
```

With jQuery v3.2.1 and jQueryUi being v1.11.4

Comment: What is exactly the `input[inputIndex]` variable?

Comment: It's a variable that is part of the library, this error happens when the file is loaded.

Comment: Are you saying that it worked when locker service was turned off?

Comment: @Logan Yes, It worked before hand but I need to make it work with a Salesforce instance that will run on 40 (summer 17) or higher, so the LockerService will be enforced and I have no other options.

Comment: Can you share any of your code?

Comment: @Logan There is no code to share as the error is happening when the component is loading, when the <ltng:require/> loads scripts, jQuery.js and bootstrap.js do not trigger any errors, but jQuery-ui is. I Hope this clears any confusion regarding this problem.

Comment: @CyrilDetrain What browser are you trying to use?

Comment: @RaviJayaramappa I am currently using Google Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit).

Comment: @CyrilDetrain Can you share the full <ltng:require> tag from your markup? I want to see the scripts you are loading and try to repro this with the same content.

Comment: @RaviJayaramappa I have edited my original post to show the <ltng:require> tag. The only error I get is when jqueryUi.js is loaded, if I remove it, I can log the object or call methods from those libraries.

Comment: @CyrilDetrain I have filed a bug for your issue. As a work around, can you use jquery v2.2.4 while we fix the bug? Please let us know here if that fixes your issue.

Comment: @RaviJayaramappa It looks like it is working with jQuery v.2.2.4 ! Thanks for the advice and I will follow the bug. Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can confirm this is reproducible. The root cause of the error is jQueryUI executing window.hasOwnProperty("document"). You can see this by opening up chrome debugger and breaking on all exceptions.
[image]

LockerService's SecureWindow does not support a 'hasOwnProperty' method. I will file a bug for this and get it fixed.

Comment: W-4088037 is the bug number if you want to reference it in a case