# jQuery issue in Lightning component in Salesforce community builder's in Edit mode

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I have a Lightning component on my SF community page with Locker Service enabled. I am using ltng:require tag to load custom JavaScript/jQuery from a static resource. The main issue is the jQuery library I think (using 2.2.4 as), it is listed on SF documentation page as working. It throws an exception in Community editor. Although the actual live page executes my custom JavaScript code successfully.
It happens only if I use API 40+ (i.e. LockerService).
[image]

Comment: If you check your network tab while loading the page, you will see that it is already being loaded, not sure what version is used though, maybe there is a conflict of libraries?

Comment: Thanks @glls . Yeah I saw that. It could be .. But it works if I add jquery 3.2.1 but then it breaks other jQuery library - jQuery UI 1.21.1.

Comment: check [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97524/how-to-use-jquery-in-lightning-communities-without-how-to-deal-with-the-jquery)

Comment: Thanks @glls .. As mentioned in the post you shared, it is not a recommended but I guess I will try if there is no other option. 
I found one more post regarding the issue I am facing with v3.2.1 with UI 1.12.1 .
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180535/jqueryui-inputinputindex-hasownproperty-is-not-a-function
I guess it is a bug in Salesforce.

Comment: @balindersingh, could you add some repro steps? The error doesn't seem related to LockerService, and could be a side effect of something else.

Comment: It looks like a jQuery conflict with Salesforce jquery..
I added jQuery 2.2.4  and when I go to community builder mode it throw this exception only if I use API 40+ (i.e. LockerService enabled) API 39- works .

Comment: Just an update.. I was able to fix the issue by using jQuery 3.2.1 with jQueryUI 1.12.1 .
I have to make small change in jQueryUI 1.12.1:
On line 204 of file change  `if (input[inputIndex].hasOwnProperty(key) && value !== undefined)` to  `if (typeof input[inputIndex].hasOwnProperty === 'function' && input[inputIndex].hasOwnProperty(key) && value !== undefined)`